# Dúvida sobre sintaxe de uma frase

Tags: português-brasileiro, sintaxe, análise-sintática

Estou estudando através do livro Novissima Gramática da Lingua Portuguesa, do Cegalla. Na lista de exercícios nº 41 temos a frase:

***"Esta viga de metal será aproveitada para a construção de minha casa"***

Eu queria que alguém pudesse me ajudar com a análise sintatica completa da frase, pq o livro (como 100% dos outros livros de português que peguei) não explicam a frase num todo: ora pedem isso, ora pedem aquilo, sem nunca juntar tudo que já foi explicado anteriormente, e fica parecendo que ou você tem adjunto adnominal, ou você tem complemento nominal, ou você tem complemento indireto e eu fico que nem louco tentando juntar a colcha de retalhos que foi criada na minha cabeça.

Enfim, o que eu pude tirar com o pouco que sei foi:

**Voz passiva**

**Sujeito =** Esta viga de metal

```
Esta: adjunto adnominal
de metal: adjunto adnominal
viga: núcleo do sujeito
(isso é algo que eu nunca vejo os livros fazerem, pegar uma frase e explicar: olha,
o sujeito é formado por isso e isso e isso, o objeto direto por isso e isso e etc. Se
alguém souber me indicar um livro que tem análises mais avançadas me falem, por favor
```

**verbo =** será aproveitada

**??? =** para a construção de minha casa

```
Aqui eu já começo a me perder na análise, pq como é uma frase na voz passiva
o verbo não irá pedir complemento, não podendo então ser objeto indireto.
Seria "para a construção" adjunto adverbial de causa? 
"de minha casa" seria adjunto adnominal de construção?
```

A quem responder se puder colocar a explicação do porque da classificação dos termos, agradeceria muito!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discuti o tema com um amigo competente, e a análise dele é a seguinte: o trecho "para a construção da minha casa" é um adjunto adverbial final -- dá finalidade à viga. Se a parte em questão fosse levada para a forma oracional "para que a casa fosse construída", poderia ser classificada como oração subordinada adverbial final. Espero que isso ajude, caso não esteja equivocado.